# Proving that the sequence of derivatives $fn'$ converges uniformly on $R$

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

In the following question I am trying to show that the sequence of derivatives $fn'$ converges uniformly on $R$

$$f_n(x)=\frac{nx^2+2x}{n}$$

So the first step would be to calculate the derivative with respect to $x$.

So then,

$$f_n'=\frac{2xn+2}{n}$$

Then taking the limit we get that,

$$lim_{n->\infty}\frac{\frac{2x}{n}+\frac{2}{n}}{\frac{n}{n}}=|2x|$$

My first question would be why is it $|2x|,$ I understand the calculation but why don't you consider when $x=0$? Is that only when you consider the pointwise limit?

Then for my workings to prove that it converges uniformly,

$$|\frac{2xn+2}{n}-2x|=\frac{2}{n}$$

Then for $\epsilon>0$ choose a $N$ such that $\frac{2}{N}<\epsilon$ and with $n>N$ then,

$$|\frac{2xn+2}{n}-2x|=\frac{2}{n}<\frac{2}{N}<\epsilon$$

Therefore the sequence of derivative converges uniformly.

So my two questions are, about the limit calculation and whether not to consider when $x=0$, and if my workings for the second part are correct.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sequence of derivatives is given by

$$ f_n'(x) = 2x + \frac{2}{n}. $$

As $n$ goes to infinity, this sequence clearly converges pointwise to $2x$ (not $|2x|$). Uniform convegence is also simple because

$$ \sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}} |f_n'(x) - 2x| = \sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}} \left| \frac{2}{n} \right| = \frac{2}{n} \to 0. $$

Comment: BTW, your proof for the uniform convergence is also correct.

Comment: so you don't need to consider when $x=0$? or is this already taken into account when you say it converges to 2x. I am a little confused with this pointwise notation

Comment: For a fixed $x$, whether it is zero or not, we have $2x + \frac{2}{n} \to 2x$ as $n$ goes to infinity. So yes, the case $x = 0$ (as all other cases) is already taken into consideration. Why should it be $|2x|$? If $x = -1$, you get the sequence $-2 + \frac{2}{n}$ which converges to $-2$, not $2 = |-2|$.

Comment: okay so then when would you have to take into consideration x=0? with something like $\frac{1}{1+nx^2}$?

Comment: @jh123: When the behaviour at $x = 0$ is different than for $x \neq 0$. In your new example, for $x \neq 0$ we have $1 + nx^2 \to \infty$ so $\frac{1}{1 + nx^2} \to 0$. However, for $x = 0$ we have $1 + nx^2 = 1$ so $\frac{1}{1 + nx^2} = 1 \to 1$.

Comment: makes sense, thanks very much for your time!